When using the flags multiple or maxFiles, the react-dropzone onDrop call back does not return any files in the acceptedFiles array
I am using the onDrop callback which expects acceptedFiles, that I can then use to append the images to a form.
What I have noticed is that when I use the maxFiles flag with a number bigger than the number of images dropped; or set the multiple flag to false, and I drop more than one image; the onDrop callback does not return any image in the acceptedFiles list.
See codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-dropzone-on-drop-not-returning-acceptedfiles-lkt5fg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A21%2C12
In this sandbox I have used maxFiles but setting multiple to false shows the same result.
As per the documentation:
If multiple is set to false and additional files are dropped, all files besides the first will be rejected.
I am wondering if I am missing anything in the method declaration to ensure files that comply are returned in the onDrop callback.
I am using the useDropzone hook:
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: acceptedFileTypes,
    maxFiles,
  });

Looked in the documentation but could not figure out what is missing, ideally any files not rejected would be part of the acceptedFiles list.
Thanks,
